# Angular2 2.0.0 How to add simple functions to @NgModule

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I would like to create a "Utility Module": tnt.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {toUpperCase} from "./tnt.utils";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    toUpperCase
  ],
  exports: [
    toUpperCase
  ]
})
export default class TntModule {}
```

Here is one util function example: tnt.utils.ts

```
export const toUpperCase= function (str:String) {
  return str.toUpperCase()
}
```

I am getting an Error:

```
ERROR in [default] /data/2016/le-tube/src/app/shared/tnt/tnt.module.ts:5:10 
Argument of type '{ imports: undefined[]; declarations: ((str: String) => string)[]; exports: ((str: String) => str...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
  Types of property 'declarations' are incompatible.
    Type '((str: String) => string)[]' is not assignable to type '(any[] | Type<any>)[]'.
      Type '(str: String) => string' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
        Type '(str: String) => string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
          Type '(str: String) => string' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): any'
```

What am I missing ? Why can't I create a module with simple functions ? I suppose I am just missing a simple detail but I can't figure it out...

Comment: I can't answer it from the info provided. However, I can advice you to use the angular cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli and toUppercase seems to me a 'pipe' candidate. For functions you should use a service.

Comment: I am using the angular-cli, I see thanks I will build a service instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not export a function from NgModule,

> exports : Array|any[]>
>
> Specifies a list of
>   directives/pipes/module that can be used within the template of any
>   component that is part of an angular module that imports this angular
>   module.

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not export functions from modules.

You have two options:

1) either create a `utililty.ts` file and create your functions in there to be exported.

```
export function utlityFunction1(param1, param2) { return param1+param2; )
```

you can import this function in your code file just like any other object.

```
import { utilityFunction } from './utility.ts'
```

2) Create a `UtilityService` and inject that into your component.

More on that here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html